# List of matrix properties which are preserved after a change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, big-list

Lately I encountered such a problem.

**Which of the properties of matrices are preserved after a change of basis ?** 
(*orthogonal basis and square matrix are preferred in the first place*)

Maybe it is a reasonable to make such a comprehensive list?
Wikipedia doesn't provide even a short list in [Change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) though it gives some answers in [Matrix_similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).
If someone knows however about such a list please give a pointer towards it. I need the list, not a bibliography.

I would like additionally to divide properties into **general** and **specific** ones, where general properties are like

symmetry, skew-symmetry, etc (*they can be or not associated with a given matrix - binary decision*) 
and 
specific properties are like
rank, determinant, trace etc.. (*they can be always characterized by a single number or a set of them*).

So I will start. Also important is to list what is **not** preserved.

What is preserved ?

**General properties:** *(if happens)*

Symmetry. *Yes.*

Skew-Symmetry. *Yes*

Orthogonality . *Yes*

Diagonality (non-zero entries only on diagonal) *No*

Positivness (all entries are positive) *No*.

**Specific properties:**

Trace. *Yes*.

Rank. *Yes*.

Determinant. *Yes*.

---

What else can be added?

....

Comment: Characteristic and minimal polynomial.

Comment: Ok. I collect them all in the table.  You are welcome to do the same on your own.

Comment: By "change of basis" do you mean [$P^{-1}AP$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#The_matrix_of_an_endomorphism) or [$P^TAP$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#The_matrix_of_a_bilinear_form)?

Comment: I prefer rather the second one in this question (orthogonal) however if someone is capable to make such discern and  list unchanged (changed) properties in both cases then such classification also would be useful.

Comment: We can for example use abbreviations for the sake of this question: OCB - orthogonal change of basis, GCB - general change of basis.

Comment: @Rahul I've always seen "change of basis" to mean conjugation, which is mainly because matrices are most often used to represent linear maps. If you want them to represent bilinear forms, you would use the second kind of transformation, though one should insist that $P$ be invertible here (if not be can simply make any square matrix zero). If the matrix represents an Hermitian form, then $P^*AP$ would be used instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Properties Preserved Under GCB:

- Rank
- Nullity
- Determinant
- Trace
- Characteristic Polynomial
- Eigenvalues
- Minimal Polynomial
- Diagonalizability
- Jordan Canonical Form

### Properties Preserved Under OCB:

- Symmetry ($A^T=A$)
- Antisymmetry ($A^T=-A$)
- Orthogonality ($A^TA=I$)
- Normality ($AA^T=A^TA$)
- Positive (semi)definite-ness
- Schur triangular form
- Matrix norm (Frobenius, Euclidean)

### Properties Preserved by Neither:

- Having positive/non-negative entries
- Image
- Null space
- Eigenvectors/Generalized eigenvectors

Comment: Nice collection, thank you Om.

Comment: However collection might have been developed vastly. Many specific matrices are listed in wikipedia [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices). For example, what can be said about **hollow matrix** [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_matrix)  under GCB or OCB ?

Comment: Pretty much any property that depends on the particular arrangement of values is not preserved by either. For example, whether or not a matrix is diagonal is not preserved. *diagonalizability*, on the other hand, is a different story.

Comment: Particular arrangement of values could be a good indicator for not preservation, but symmetry is also some kind of arrangement. Where is a difference ? In using transposition in a description of property which might mean that transpose is somehow a key operator in arrangement for OCB at least ? (4 times used on the list)

Comment: There is an intimate connection between transposes and dot products

Comment: ... and consequently projections also.. transpose is in some way unique as it is operation of changing only arrangement without changing  values (with its great importance incomparable to the other such operations)..