# Matrix equation that doesn't change its form under a change of basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to continue [the thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782042/list-of-matrix-properties-which-are-preserved-after-a-change-of-basis) with preserved properties under a change of basis (*I'm developing my reasearch*), however the problem is so distinct that I've decided to ask a new question (*I hope the question will not be classified as duplicate*)

My question  is now:

**What are matrix equations that don't change own form under orthogonal change of basis ?**
(*i.e. equations are satisfied by an old and a new matrix after a change of basis*)

My candidates so far :

If $g_i(A)$ is any polynomial function **without constant matrix** (e.g. $g_i(A) =2A^2+3A$) then  following forms of equations are, I  assume ( *please, Dear Reader, confirm or deny that it is a true*), satisfying the condition mentioned above:

- $g_1(A)+g_2(A^T)+  g_3(AA^T)+g_4(A^TA) = 0$ ,
- $g_1(A)+g_2(A^T)+  g_3(AA^T)+g_4(A^TA) = I$ ,
- $g_1(A)+g_2(A^T)+  g_3(AA^T)+g_4(A^TA) = -I$  (and others = any
  $k*I$).

From this we have, for example, conditions for preserved *symmetry, skew-symmetry, orthogonality, normality* [mentioned earlier by Om.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782042/list-of-matrix-properties-which-are-preserved-after-a-change-of-basis)  and much more...

**Edit 1.**
The same is probably true for equation

- $g_1(A)g_2(A^T)g_3(AA^T)g_4(A^TA) = kI$

**Edit 2.** (5 days)
It's worth to notice that the pattern can be extended also for equations with many different matrices. From that we have preserved relations between matrices such as:

- commutativity $AB-BA=0$
- transpose  $A^T-B=0$
- inverse $ AB=I $ .

*(As we see proposition is rather important so it seems that it should have own name. But has it ? Maybe someone knows ?)*

---

**Are there any other such unchanged equations for matrices changed under new basis**?

Comment: This can be formulated in tensor language, where it is surely more studied. You consider a matrix $A=(a^i{}_j)$ as a two-index tensor and you are looking for equations in $a^i{}_j$ that are "covariant". (*not sure if it is useful*)

Comment: Anyway,  you can add to the list polynomial equations of the form $p(A)=0$ where $p(0)=\lambda I$, with $\lambda$ being a scalar and $I$ being the identity matrix.

Comment: @ Giuseppe Negro Is it not the case as  ".. (and others = any $k∗I$)" where $k$ is scalar ?

Comment: Right, that had escaped me. I am writing a small note in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this post, let $A^\star$ denote the transpose conjugate of $A$. 
Assume that $A$ is normal, meaning that $A^\star A = A A^\star$.

Then, if $p(z, \overline z)$ is a complex polynomial, the equation 
$$\tag{1}
p(A, A^\star)=0$$
(here $A^\star$ is the transpose conjugate) is unitarily invariant in the sense that if $A$ satisfies (1) then $A'=UAU^\star$ also satisfies (1). Note that the constant term of the polynomial must be evaluated to a scalar matrix, e.g. if $p(z, \overline z)=z\overline z +1$ then $p(A, A^\star)=AA^\star + I$.

If $A$ is not normal, the equation (1) must be replaced with 
$$
p_1(A)+p_2(A^\star) + p_3(AA^\star) + p_4(A^\star A)=0, $$ 
where $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ are polynomials. This is exactly what you did above.

---

You can find more invariant equations, but this requires the introduction of the so-called "functional calculus":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus

The most important example is the exponential equation: 
$$
\tag{2} e^A =B.$$ 
If $A=UA'U^\star$ and $B=UB'U^\star$ then $(A, B)$ solve (2) if and only if $(A', B')$ solve (2). (Here $U$ is a unitary matrix).

Comment: OK. I must rethink your answer :)

Comment: However I would prefer to avoid complex numbers in the analysis _(if possible)_

Comment: @Widawens: If $A$ is real then $A^\star=A^T$ and everything here holds true. That's not a problem. The only caveat is the fact that $p(A, A^T)$ (or $p(A, A^\star)$ in the complex case) is not well defined if $A$ is not normal. In that case, the polynomial equation must be written as follows:$$p_1(A)+p_2(A^\star)+p_3(A^\star A) +p_4(AA^\star)=0,$$where $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ are polynomials. This is exactly what you did above, by the way.

Comment: Your remarks, Giuseppe, are very helpful. So I'm glad  to have find some formula. I wonder also whether it is some special name for $AA^T$ or $A^{T}A$ ($AA^{*}$) because they evidently play important role in LA. If not I would propose transsquare of A :)

Comment: I am glad to have helped. I don't know of any widely accepted name for $A^\star A$, except for "A-star-A" (mathematician's name) or "A-dagger-A" (physicist's name). :-) But you should ask some expert in operator theory, surely there are jargons to describe those things, they are quite common.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any expert in OT, all hope is here.