# How to Show $2$ Matrices Are NOT Unitarily/Orthogonally Equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My professor told me that it is much easier to show that $2$ matrices are **not** unitarily [orthogonally] equivalent than to show that it is. So, this got me thinking, what are some criterias for this?

$2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are unitarily/orthogonal equiv. if $A$ = $Q^{-1} B Q$, where $Q$ is a unitary/orthogonal matrix, right? But, how do I apply this definition to show that no such $Q$ can exist? Is this the right approach? If not, how should I go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: do you have any matrices in particular?

Comment: Take two matrices with the same eigenvalues but one symmetric, the other one not. Then they cannot be unitarily equivalent.

Comment: I don't have any particular matrices, but I was just wondering in general.

Answer (score 1):

On [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1782224/81360), I list properties that are preserved by orthogonal changes of basis. If two matrices differ in any of these properties (e.g. they have different traces), then the matrices cannot be similar.

An interesting criterion which I didn't mention on the page is that matrices are orthogonally equivalent if and only if $w(A,A^*)$ and $w(B,B^*)$ have the same trace for every word $w$ on two letters.

Comment: What is a word on two letters of a matrix pair?

Comment: @algebraicPavel a word is an "ordered product". For instance, the [free group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group) contains every word on two letters.