# Do row operations preserve any properties of matrices besides row space and null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Elementary row operations on a matrix preserve row space, null space, rank, nullity, and invertibilty.  They do not preserve determinant, trace, or column space.

Inspired by [List of matrix properties which are preserved after a change of basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782042/list-of-matrix-properties-which-are-preserved-after-a-change-of-basis) , I would like to ask:

Are there any other interesting properties preserved by elementary row operations?

Comment: I would want to inform you that the answer you have accepted is incorrect and it's just AI-generated text.

Comment: You wrote that elementary row operations do not preserve determinants or trace, so there is an inconsistency in accepting an Answer that claims eigenvalues (and eigenvectors!) are preserved.  I've down voted the Answer accordingly.

Comment: I've seen the OP be an honest participant here, and I'm sure they will want to unaccept the faulty answer once they are aware of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most important: If a matrix is viewed as an *augmented matrix* consisting of a coefficient matrix and a RHS vector, then the solution set is invariant under row operations.

Comment: The solution space is the same thing as the nullspace, which OP mentions in their question already.

Comment: @AlexProvost You mean because $Ax = b \iff \begin{bmatrix} A & | & b\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x \\ \hline  -1\end{bmatrix} = 0$ ?  That's a neat way of looking at the solution set.